# Show preview of URL while entering a link in UITextView

Tags: ios, url, uitextview

I need to show a preview of a URL (like FB and WhatsApp do), while the user is entering a link in a UITextView.

Is there a library on iOS to grab it, or do we have to make our own?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I need to show a preview of a URL (like FB and WhatsApp do), while the user is entering a link in a UITextView.

Is there a library on iOS to grab it, or do we have to make our own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not provide this functionality by default.
You will have to build your own or use an open source solution.

This project might provide what you need:
https://github.com/itsmeichigo/URLPreview